# delete child rows of a table

Tags: mysql, database

If i have this structure:

**table users**

```
id_user
1
2
```

**table lists**

```
id_lists    name_list   users_id_user
    1           Work              1
    2           work              2
```

**lists_has_users**

```
users_id_user   lists_id_lists
    1                      2
    2                      1
```

What I want is, when delete the `id_lists`, I also want to delete all the users that are members of that list in `list_has_users`

For example if i delete the `id_lists 1`, the `lists_id_lists 1` should  also be deleted.

At the moment i get: `Cannot delete or update a parent row`

How solve this?

Comment: Modify your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to specify `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: @Michael, add as an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though you have a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint defined which enforces referential integrity, and prohibits you from deleting a parent row if children exist.  Modify your foreign key to include `ON DELETE CASCADE` to force deletion of child rows.

Use `DESCRIBE lists_has_users` to get the FK's symbol if you don't know it.

```
ALTER TABLE lists_has_users DROP FOREIGN KEY `key_symbol`;
ALTER TABLE lists_has_users ADD FOREIGN KEY (lists_id_lists) REFERENCES lists (id_lists) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

You may want to add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` as well, so that the `lists_has_users` row changes if the id of `lists` ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting from `lists` you have to delete from `lists_has_users` as you seem to have integrity checks enabled.